# My code to connect and display the contents of a ftp server does not cwd beyond /[dir]/

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I can't seem to be able to change directory past /ubuntu/ on archive.ubuntu.com, and I suspect my code to change to the wrong directory. Where is my bug?

```
from ftplib import FTP
from tkinter import *

ftp = FTP("archive.ubuntu.com")
ftp.login()

window = Tk()
window.geometry("640x480")


def listdir():
    print(ftp.dir())
    [child.destroy() for child in window.winfo_children()]
    for x in ftp.nlst():
        Button(window, text=x, command=(lambda: cdir(x))).pack()


def cdir(x):
    f = ftp.pwd()+"/"+x
    ftp.cwd(f)
    listdir()


listdir()

window.mainloop()
```

this is simple code to reproduce my problem in my larger application.

system: windows
python runtime: python 3.8
How would it be possible to prevent this bug? I can change directory just fine using python command line. ftplib isn't throwing any errors, I have tried printing every command that I run on ftp.

Comment: compared to my other application, yes.

Comment: the tkinter stuff just helps you actually see whats going on. I can see if it behaves the same without tkinter.

Comment: it worked fine without tkinter, just running through the directories: while true loop with ```ftp.dir()``` and ```ftp.cwd(input("dir>"))```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be wanting early binding in your `lambda` function. Change from

```
lambda: cdir(x)
```

to:

```
lambda y=x: cdir(y)
```

Otherwise you get the value of `x` when the function is called, rather than the one when the function was created.

---

*(Obviously you still need to tell your code about the difference between files and directories because with above fix in place you can then get to navigate as far as buttons representing actual files, and clicking on those will give an error when it tries to change directory to them. But the above will fix the issue that you are encountering right now.)*

Comment: What exact buttons are you clicking on that are not working for you?